# Listen to selection text change in webView android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to notify the user when text selection changes in WebView Android .

I tried to use`setOnTouchListener` and listen to

```
android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

and compare last selection text with new one after touch up  , using:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:js.callback(window.getSelection().toString())");
```

and

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
public class WebAppInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void callback(String value) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), value);
            selected = value;
            if (selected.length() > 0) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), selected, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

But I have problem that when user drag/change selection cursor , `OnTouch` not fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached sufficient enough solution for my problem , but still don't know why `onTouch` not fired when drag cursor .

here , i uses `setOnInterval()` to check selection text every 1000ms and IF there is a change  , it fire to `WebAppInterface`

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
myWebView.loadData("Logcat is a tool that dumps a log of system messages. The messages include a stack trace when the device throws an error, as well as log messages written from your application and those written using JavaScript console APIs" +
        "<script>" +
        "var text='';setInterval(function(){ if(window.getSelection().toString() && text!==window.getSelection().toString()){text=window.getSelection().toString();console.log(text);Android.showToast(text); }}, 1000);" +
        "</script>" +,"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
        Log.d("MyApplication", message );
    }
});

public class WebAppInterface {
    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```